# Azure form recognizer - In case of dot matrix printer '0' (zero) is recognized as '8'

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

On invoice image with dot matrix print '0' zero is recognized as '8' on azure form recognizer data extraction.

sample image is attached , here 15000.00 is the value but it recognizes
as 15888.88 ...

[image: sample image with 15000.00 printed]

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a resolution and image quality issue. It is hard even for a human looking at this text to identify if this is a 0 or an 8. What is the confidence that Form Recognizer returns for the 0